# Convert a .txt file to .asc using shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following text file:

```
ifile.txt
1.1 4.5
2.3 2.3
3.4 30.5
```

I would like to add one line (`%file1`) at the beginning and then convert it to `.asc` file.

I used the following command:

```
(echo "%file1" ; cat ifile.txt)  > ofile.asc
```

But the output came as:

```
ofile.asc
%file1
1.1 4.5^M
2.3 2.3^M
3.4 30.5^M
```

Desired output is:

```
ofile.asc
%file1
1.1 4.5
2.3 2.3
3.4 30.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `tr` instead of `cat` to remove DOS line break characters from original file:

```
{ echo "%file1"; tr -d '\r' < ifile.txt; } > ofile.asc
```

Also there is no need to fork a shell as we can use `{ ... }` to group many commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to eliminate `^M` characters:

```
{ echo "%file1" ; sed ‘s/^M//‘ file.txt ; } > ofile.asc
```